# 2 icloud acounts

Tags: iphone

My husband has an iPhone 5s, and my stepdaughter has an iPhone 4 as this is her first phone.

They both have same iTunes and iCloud account. All we want to do is disconnect the iCloud account from the 4s, and switch this off on her phone as when we are deleting some of the contacts that are in the 4s, which are the same in the 5s,
it's deleting in both phones, so we do not want to delete the account and clear the 4s in case this happens with the 5s.

We have also deleted the 4s account that was showing on the 5s, so they were not connected but the same thing is still happening. I have also turned of the iCloud backup on the 4s, but still has made no difference. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to completely [wipe & reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4137) her iPhone 4 & set it up with her own [new account](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204316).

You can then set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060), which will provide parental controls & also allow her to re-download any apps/tunes etc that were previously purchased by any of the family members.

Contacts, etc will need to be set up again from scratch.
Game progress will also be lost.

Comment: Keeping in mind that many apps will not work on family member phones. Before switching to family sharing give this article a read: Why David Sparks Is Quitting Family Sharing http://macsparky.com/blog/2015/1/quitting-family-sharing

Comment: @DaveNelson Interesting - though tbh I've been using it since it was introduced & haven't hit any of those issues yet. We don't have iTunes Match, we've always kept duplicate manually synced [or not] iTunes libs, since before FS. Personally, I wouldn't dream of sharing my own iTunes/iCloud accounts with my daughter

Comment: we recently gave it another try in our house and after a couple of months it was more trouble than it was worth. Hopefully it gets polished in the future because I think it is a great idea.